# Arcpy: MultipleRingBuffer error - Says data does not exist or is not supported

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-000732

I'm somewhat new to Python and am working on automating some of the daily processes we do at my company. In this code example, I'm trying to automate pulling in data from a CSV file, creating buffers and drive time around that data, and then appending spatial data to those created trade areas.

Originally, I was trying to do this on multiple rows in the CSV file. However, I was encountering a lot of errors so I wanted to focus on a CSV file where there was only one row first and then focus on multiple rows. I've been making some good process, but have now encountered an error that says my point feature class does not exist or is not supported when I try to perform a buffer analysis on it. I know the data does exist, because it is in the geodatabase. Any thoughts? This is the error message.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Users\Andy.Rowlands\AHR.Data\Individual.Rocks.Projects\Python.Implementation_July2016\InternalModel_PythonScript_SingleSite.py", line 74, in <module>
    arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(fcLocation, fcBuffer, [0.5, 1, 3], "Miles")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 865, in MultipleRingBuffer
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset LocationXY_DesMoines_Hickman_MerleHay does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (MultipleRingBuffer).
```

Here is my code snippet. Everything up to the feature class conversion is working fine.

```py
#create GetParameter for input csv table that has store location and lat/long
inputTable = "X:\Users\Andy.Rowlands\AHR.Data\REF.Requests\August2016\DesMoines.HickmanMerleHay\Hickman.MerleHay.LatLong.csv"

#assign variables for input table
xCoord = "Long"
yCoord = "Lat"
outLayer = "LocationXY_"

#create XY layer for location
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(inputTable, xCoord, yCoord, outLayer, spatialRef)
print(arcpy.GetCount_management(outLayer))

#create cursor to access csv table; acquire name of site location
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(outLayer)
for row in cursor:
    location = row.Location
print location

#create file geodatabase for site's spatial data
folderPath = myWorkspace
geoDBname = "{0}.gdb".format(location)
print geoDBname
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(myWorkspace, geoDBname)

#create layer name for converting XY layer to feature class data
fcLocation = outLayer + location
print fcLocation
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(outLayer, geoDBname, fcLocation)
print ("DONE")
#1 thru 63 is good

#create layer name for buffer data
#perform multi-ring buffer analysis on location
bufferString = "Buffer_"
fcBuffer = bufferString + fcLocation
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(fcLocation, fcBuffer, [0.5, 1, 3], "Miles")
print ["DONE"]
```

Based on the comments, I've gone through and printed fcLocation and fcBuffer and got the following output.

```py
>>> print fcLocation
LocationXY_DesMoines_Hickman_MerleHay
>>> print fcBuffer
Buffer_LocationXY_DesMoines_Hickman_MerleHay
```

I also tried running the BufferAnalysis with outLayer, and that did not work either. That resulted in the following error.

```py
>>> arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(outLayer, fcBuffer, [0.5, 1, 3], "Miles")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 865, in MultipleRingBuffer
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000339: Input LocationXY_ does not have OIDs
```

Oh and I will add that the Feature Class conversion/creation DOES work. A point feature class is created in the geodatabase.

Just tried GBG's suggestion. Here is the code I wrote:

```py
#create XY layer for location
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(inputTable, xCoord, yCoord, outLayer, spatialRef)
print(arcpy.GetCount_management(outLayer))

#create cursor to access csv table; acquire name of site location
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(outLayer)
for row in cursor:
    location = row.Location
print location

#create file geodatabase for site's spatial data
folderPath = myWorkspace
geoDBname = "{0}.gdb".format(location)
print geoDBname
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(myWorkspace, geoDBname)

#create layer name for converting XY layer to feature class data
fcLocation = outLayer + location
print fcLocation
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outLayer, fcLocation)
#arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(outLayer, geoDBname, fcLocation)
print ("DONE")
print fcLocation
```

Same error message as before. Says dataset does not exist or is not supported.

```py
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset
LocationXY_DesMoines_Hickman_MerleHay does not exist or is not
supported Failed to execute (MultipleRingBuffer).
```

Comment: What happens when you print the values of fcLocation and fcBuffer prior to running MultipleRingBuffer and then use those values to test the tool outside your code from its tool dialog or in a code snippet of a few lines?

Comment: What happens if you run MultipleRingBuffer with outLayer as the input instead of fcLocation? I'm guessing that FeatureClassToFeatureClass isn't doing anything because outLayer is a feature layer, not a feature class.

Comment: This is the result of printing fcLocation, fcBuffer outside of the code: `>>> print fcLocation
LocationXY_DesMoines_Hickman_MerleHay
>>> print fcBuffer
Buffer_LocationXY_DesMoines_Hickman_MerleHay`   I also tried running MultipleRingBuffer with outLayer and nothing changed. The FeatureClassToFeatureClass is working; it's creating a feature class in the geodatabase.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to keep improving it through revisions rather than creating a comment trail that the volunteers who answer questions here may not have time to read.

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question which I think is superfluous to the snippet required to reproduce your problem and just acts as a distraction for you and anyone trying to debug it.  For example: `import arcview`, `arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Business")` and `arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")` but I am sure there are more.

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and heavily revise your question so that it becomes clear to all potential answerers what code snippet you are currently asking about (remove all other code from your question) and what happens when you run it.  I think the answer by @GBG is most probably correct but the question is meandering rather than clear.

Answer (score 1):

The MakeXYEventLayer function has limited use beyond displaying data.  Save the event layer to memory using arcpy.CopyFeatures_management() after you import the xy data.  Then run the buffer on those saved data.